# Django unable to change name for url pattern

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm trying to refactor some of my code so that it is consistent, i.e. the name:

```
path('create_project', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='create-project'),
```

I have also changed it in my template:

```
<a href="create-project">
   <img src="{% static 'project_portal/image/icon_add_circle.png' %}" alt="Add" width="32">
</a>
```

but now I get the following:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/si/create-project/
Raised by:  project_portal.views.ProjectDetailView
```

How can changing a "_" to "-" break the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't actually use the name.

```
<a href="{% url "create-project" %}">
```

Comment: Ok, I've got something really wrong here, I can't get this link to work at all, I can't go back either it seems. Is there anywhere else that this might appear in a django site that I have missed?

Comment: What happens, exactly?

Comment: I just get the above error. this link I set up about a month ago and has always worked fine until I did this, trying to revert back to last commit currently in case it is a VScode bug as I am unable to just undo what I have done, it just does not work now.

Comment: Just rolled back to last commit and it still gives a page not found, I'm lost to be honest. Not a VSCode issue, it must be my code. just closed everything and run the server from the command line.

Comment: Annoyingly could not solve this issue, I have marked Daniel's comment as correct, as he quite rightly corrected my code, but I had to delete all the code for the view Form and html and url completely and start again as I was unable to find the error. Appologies for anyone trying to find a solution here.